# Dynamically remove blanks from a range of excel cells

Tags: dynamic, excel, vba

I have a named range of data, called 'data'.  I'm trying to find a formula or array formula that will return data in a new range of cells, but will all the blank rows missing.

i.e. `data` is:

```
row   x    y    
1     A    77    
2          
3     B    23    
4     A    100    
5
```

And my new range is:

```
row    x    y    
1     A    77    
3     B    23    
4     A    100
```

It's ok if the blank rows end up at the end of the array.  So far I am stumped

Comment: Does row column exist or are there just x and y? Could happen that x contains something and y doesn't or viceversa?

Comment: @nick rulez" A row column does exist, and x and y are both either filled or blank.  It's never the case that x is blank and y isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the special cells method for this.  Either with vba or Manually.

**Manually**

2007/2010

Select column A
Home Tab -Find & Select - Goto Special - Blanks - Ok
Home Tab - Delete Cells - Entire Row - Ok

**VBA**

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()
    Activesheet.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

If you want to leave the original data intact and copy the range to another sheet try something like:

```
Sub DeleteBlanks()

    Dim vArray As Variant
    '// Get an array of your data
    vArray = Sheet1.UsedRange
    '// Copy the data to another sheet
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vArray, 1), UBound(vArray, 2)).Value = vArray
    '// Delete blanks
    Sheet2.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

**FORMULA**

If you really need a formula take a look here:

[Remove Blanks - Array Formula](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2007/09/16/excel-remove-blank-cells/#array)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a filter where you exclude blanks from the appropriate column(s)?

Alternatively, you could create an additional flag column which designates each row to be included based on your blank criteria (eg, `IF(OR(X="",Y=""),0,1)`) and use it to filter your data.

Comment: I don't want to use a filter because I want the new range to automatically update when I change the original range.

Answer (score 3):

I like Chris's advice.
This is a vba approach.
Try it on a copy of your file.

```
Sub delete_empty_rows()
Dim last As Long, i As Long
last = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
For i = last To 1 Step -1
    If Application.CountA(Range("A" & i).EntireRow) = 0 Then
        Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```